# React Redux async actions handling

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have general function for handling input onChange:

```
export function onChange(e) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        const payload = {};
        payload[e.target.id] = e.target.value;
        dispatch({
            type: e.target.name,
            payload
        })
    }
}
```

after some inputs changes (for ex. ones for set how much rows per table I want to fetch 30 or 60) I need to fire fetch function.

But when I'm calling fetch() function right after onChange - fetching is starting before onChange changes props that are part oof request url - request is incorect.

How do I handle such async actions to strt fetching after onChange changes the redux state

**EDIT**
the second function I want to call is

```
export function searchContacts(e, props) {

return (dispatch) => {
    let propsReceived = props.allContacts;

    let searchString = "?page="      + propsReceived.paginate +
                       "&orderBy="  + propsReceived.order    +
                       "&sortedBy=" + propsReceived.sort     +
                       "&limit="    + propsReceived.limit;
    if(e){
        let search = e.target.value;
        searchString += "&search=first_name:" + search +";first_name:"+ search;
    }
    let url = ALL_CONTACTS + searchString;
    return  dispatch(getContacts(url));
}
```

And I'm calling these two function like that:

```
<select className="input-select select-contacts-nav"
        onChange={(e)=>{
                 this.props.onChange(e);
                 this.props.searchContacts(null, this.props);
        }}
        value={this.props.allContacts.limit}
        id="limit"
        name="ALL_CONTACTS"
>
    <option value="30"> 30</option>
    <option value="60"> 60</option>
    <option value="100">100</option>
</select>
```

But `this.props.searchContacts` starts before `this.props.onChange`

Comment: Can you show where exactly you want to call `fetch`?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was in `onChange` event - it has "pending state transition." 
More info here - [React form onChange->setState one step behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773839/react-form-onchange-setstate-one-step-behind)