# react this.setState Warning on mounted or mounting

Tags: javascript, events, reactjs

I am consistently getting:

> Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting
>   component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted
>   component. This is a no-op. Please check the code for the SearchInput
>   component.

I have tried following these:
https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/two-way-binding-helpers.html#linkedstatemixin-before-and-after

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21029999/react-js-identifying-different-inputs-with-one-onchange-handler

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773839/react-form-onchange-setstate-one-step-behind

The problem is simple: when a user types into the input field capture the input via the `onChange` attribute and `setState`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class SearchInput extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      inputValue: ''
    };
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <input
        type="text"
        value={this.state.inputValue}
        onChange={this.onChange} />
    );
  }

  onChange(e) {
    console.log('yo');
    this.setState({ inputValue: e.target.value });
  }
}

export default SearchInput;
```

How do I mount my component so that the warning goes away and I can update user input state?

**UPDATE**
I recently changed my `.babelrc` file to this:

```
{
  "presets": ["latest-minimal", "stage-1", "react"],
  "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
}
```

following this: https://github.com/gabmontes/babel-preset-latest-minimal

But as soon as I revert back to what I had before:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015", "stage-1", "react"],
  "plugins": ["react-hot-loader/babel"]
}
```

the warning went away.

Something in the `latest-minimal` not jiving.

Comment: And under what circumstances do you get a warning?

Comment: `state = {
      inputValue: ""
}`
try assigning state above constructor instead inside

Comment: 100% percent sure that the error is not about the code above.

Comment: @zerkms I'm using webpack to load the index.html which has a root entry point. The only component is this one `<SearchInput />`

Comment: @FurkanO can you please elaborate on this?

Comment: @M.Holmes so what do you do next to get that warning?

Comment: Oh I see. I just type into the input field

Comment: @zerkms check the UPDATE

Answer (score -1):

use defaultValue instead of value.

```
render() {
 return (
  <input
    type="text"
    defaultValue ={this.state.inputValue}
    onChange={this.onChange} />
 );
}
```

checkout this uncontrolled components concept:

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#uncontrolled-components

basically Input maintain its own state when you set value use expression it will trigger state change in input component (unmounted component) while rendering SearchInput component.