# ReactJS: doing calculations to setState, and updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'd like to have two input numeric fields, `value1` and `value2` and add the values of those two fields. The `sum` will then be saved in `this.state.sum`. I also don't want to use a "submit" button. Some code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import addNumbers from "./components/addNumbers"

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      value1: 10,
      value2: 3,
      sum: 13
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    //first setState call works fine
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
    //call addNumbers function
    const sum = addNumbers(this.state.value1, this.statevalue2)
   //this second setState() call will lag by one step
    this.setState({sum: sum})
    console.log(newBarData)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
        <input name="value1" type="number" placeholder="10" onBlur={this.handleChange} />
        <input name="value2" type="number" placeholder="3" onBlur={this.handleChange} />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

What happens is: the second `setState()` call won't be effected until I make a *second* change on the page. This is quite a [common issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28773839/react-form-onchange-setstate-one-step-behind), but I'm not sure how to work around it. I'd like for it to be able to proc immediately after the user updates the form. In the actual use-case, there'll be some calculations based on user-input values, then visualized on a graph (plotly.js), and I want to be able to update the graph "live" after each input field change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use currying to create different handler in one piece of code (see: `makeHandleChange`). Then you can use `componentDidUpdate` to check if the value of your inputs changed to update your sum state value.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import addNumbers from "./components/addNumbers"

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    value1: 10,
    value2: 3,
    sum: 13
  }

  componentDidUpdate(lastProps, lastState) {
    const valueChanged = this.state.value1 !== lastState.value1 || this.state.value2 != lastState.value2
    if (valueChanged) {
      const sum = addNumbers(this.state.value1, this.state.value2)
      this.setState({ sum }) 
    }
  }

  makeHandleChange = id => ({ target: { value } }) => {
    this.setState({
      [`value${id}`]: value
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form>
          <input name="value1" type="number" placeholder="10" onBlur={this.makeHandleChange(1)} />
          <input name="value2" type="number" placeholder="3" onBlur={this.makeHandleChange(2)} />
          <div>the sum is: {this.state.sum}</div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: This answer somewhat works, but triggers en error: "Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops". I suspect it's due to the `if(true) {...}` statement in `componentDidUpdate()`, but I dunno how this would proc more than twice.

Comment: I have tested my code, I can't reproduce your issue: https://jsfiddle.net/o7zgd8fs/2/

Comment: it still happens sporadically for me (possibly because the real use case has 4 inputs?). Also, I use 

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: parseFloat(event.target.value)})
  }
```

Instead of your version of `makeHandleChange`; could that be an issue?